# MYSQl, select from two tables, count, with exception

Tags: php, mysql, database, count

If i use this query:

```
SELECT map.x,map.y,users.username,Count(username) as count 
FROM map LEFT JOIN users ON (map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y) 
WHERE map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2 
GROUP BY map.x,map.y
ORDER BY map.y DESC,map.x
```

I get this result:

[image]

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AOgH.png)

(I don't need the usernames, it is here just for the explanation)
But i don't want to count for example "valaki", so i would like to get a result like this:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URGFs.png]

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/URGFs.png)

But with this code i get someting completely different:

```
SELECT map.x,map.y,users.username,Count(username) as count 
FROM map LEFT JOIN users ON (map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y) 
WHERE map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND users.username!='valaki'
GROUP BY map.x,map.y
ORDER BY map.y DESC,map.x
```

This:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO1Iy.png]

(Original image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pO1Iy.png)

(Those places where players aren't 'valaki', but i need those to where nobody is.)

If somebody can fix my query, i would be very happy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try,

```
SELECT  map.x, map.y, 
        users.username,
        Count(username <> 'valaki') as totalCount 
FROM    map 
        LEFT JOIN users 
            ON map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y 
WHERE   map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2 
GROUP   BY map.x,map.y
ORDER   BY map.y DESC, map.x
```

Remember that `Count(username <> 'valaki')` is valid only in `mysql`, if you happen try on other RDBMS, you can do it like this,

```
COUNT(CASE WHEN username <> 'valaki' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try something like this:

```
select map.x, map.y, group_concat(users.username),
       sum(case when username <> 'valaki' then 1 else 0 end) as SumNoValaki
from map left join
     users 
     ON map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y 
WHERE   map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2 
GROUP   BY map.x,map.y
ORDER   BY map.y DESC, map.x
```

Your query is arbitrarily choosing one username to put on each row.  Wouldn't you want to see all of them?

Answer (score 0):

Just try the query bellow, You just need to add "AND users.username IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(username) > 1" to your where statement.

It will get you clean results of the data you need to check.

```
SELECT map.x,map.y,users.username,Count(username) as count 
FROM map LEFT JOIN users ON (map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y) 
WHERE map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND users.username IS NOT NULL AND COUNT(username) > 1 
GROUP BY map.x,map.y
ORDER BY map.y DESC,map.x
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT map.x,map.y,users.username,Count(username) as count 
FROM map 
LEFT JOIN users ON (map.x=users.x AND map.y=users.y AND users.username!='valaki') 
WHERE map.y BETWEEN 0 AND 2 AND map.x BETWEEN 0 AND 2
GROUP BY map.x,map.y
ORDER BY map.y DESC,map.x
```